# Creating .pem file programmatically in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, openssl, pem, csr

I am trying to create a PEM file programmatically from a Certificate Signing Request using Objective-C and the OpenSSL library in an iPhone app. I have generated the CSR (of type X509_REQ *) by following Adria Navarro's answer to this question:

[Generating an OpenSSL Certificate Signing Request in iOS with Keychain stored keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456237/generating-an-openssl-certificate-signing-request-in-ios-with-keychain-stored-ke)

I've confirmed that the CSR is valid by printing it out to the console.

Below is my code for creating the PEM file (CertificateSigningRequest.pem). It ends up creating a blank file (0 bytes and no text). Am I doing something wrong, such that it is not able to write to the file via PEM_write_X509_REQ? (Note that I'm checking the file by downloading the app folder via Organizer.)

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide, and let me know if I should provide additional info.

```
- (void)createPemFileWithCertificateSigningRequest:(X509_REQ *)certSigningRequest
{
    //delete existing PEM file if there is one
    [self deletePemFile];

    //create empty PEM file
    NSString *pemFilePath = [self pemFilePath];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:pemFilePath contents:nil attributes:nil])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error creating file for PEM");
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error creating file for PEM" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Could not create file at the following location:\n\n%@", pemFilePath] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        return;
    }

    //get a FILE struct for the PEM file
    NSFileHandle *outputFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:pemFilePath];
    FILE *pemFile = fdopen([outputFileHandle fileDescriptor], "w");

    //write the CSR to the PEM file
    PEM_write_X509_REQ(pemFile, certSigningRequest);
}

- (NSString *)pemFilePath
{
    NSString *documentsFolder = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CertificateSigningRequest.pem"];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that my issue was that I wasn't closing the file after writing to it. Adding the final line to this method did the trick.

```
- (void)createPemFileWithCertificateSigningRequest:(X509_REQ *)certSigningRequest
{
    //...

    //write the CSR to the PEM file
    PEM_write_X509_REQ(pemFile, certSigningRequest);

    //close the file
    fclose(pemFile); //THIS MAKES EVERYTHING WORK =)
}
```

Comment: I found every solution of CSR with RSA so what about EC, could you please help me out to find CSR with EC using OpenSSL ?