# Generating CSR from SecKey using OpenSSL

Tags: ios, swift, openssl

I have created a public/private key pair (Elliptic Curve) with `SecKeyGeneratePair`.

How can I use the `SecKey` instances to generate a CSR using OpenSSL in Swift?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456237/generating-an-openssl-certificate-signing-request-in-ios-with-keychain-stored-ke?rq=1) but not in Swift.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell Apple's own Security framework does not have an API currently exposed f or generating CSR's. It is technically OpenSSL wrapped; so in case you do have OpenSSL ( I personally prefer LibreSSL, libtls makes life easy ).

*As an alternative you can also use Commoncrypto, which my answer won't cover but there are many many examples out there*

So lets go through the steps of finding out how to do this. I found that the easiest way to work with `OpenSSL` is to ignore the documentation completely and go straight to reading source.

To achieve what we need, we need to 'replicate' the following 2 commands:

`openssl ecparam -out server.key -name prime256v1 -genkey`

`openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr`

**Important Note:** Be sure to pick a *secure* curve. Use openssl ecparam -list_curves to get a list of supported curves by your version of openssl. [Read more](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to)

**Step 1** Generating the key

`ecparam` tells us we have to look in sslsource/apps/openssl/ecparam.c first.

The source gives us 3 steps:
Set up BIO for writing, setting up group parameters and finally generating the key.

**Step 2** Generating the CSR

Following the same principles but this time looking in `req.c` and some code in `apps.c` which contains some boilerplate code used in `req.c`

I used this method to create a crude but working proof of concept that runs in swift, you can check it out on github here: [CertificateTool](https://github.com/jabwd/CertificateTool)
The code will run on any system you can compile the swift4+ toolchain on and some version of openSSL.

**Edit:**

Generating the EC Secret key:

```
//
//  ECKey.swift
//  CertificateToolPackageDescription
//
//  Created by Antwan van Houdt on 10/01/2018.
//
import CLibreSSL

public class ECKey {
    internal let secretKey: OpaquePointer
    private let group: OpaquePointer

    public init() {
        group = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1)
        EC_GROUP_set_asn1_flag(group, OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE)
        EC_GROUP_set_point_conversion_form(group, POINT_CONVERSION_COMPRESSED)

        secretKey = EC_KEY_new()
        EC_KEY_set_group(secretKey, group)
        EC_KEY_generate_key(secretKey)
    }

    deinit {
        EC_KEY_free(secretKey)
        EC_GROUP_free(group)
    }
}
```

Creating the signing request:

```
//
//  CertificateRequest.swift
//  CertificateToolPackageDescription
//
//  Created by Antwan van Houdt on 10/01/2018.
//
import CLibreSSL

public enum NIDType: String {
    case email    = "emailAddress"
    case hostName = "CN"
    case organizationalUnit = "OU"
    case organization      = "O"
    case city        = "L"
    case state       = "ST"
    case countryCode = "C"
}

public class CertificateSigningRequest {
    private let request: UnsafeMutablePointer<X509_REQ>
    private let key:     ECKey
    private let name:    UnsafeMutablePointer<X509_NAME>

    public init(key: ECKey, email: String, hostName: String, organizationalUnit: String, organization: String, countryCode: String, state: String, city: String) {
        request = X509_REQ_new()
        self.key = key

        name = X509_NAME_new()
        X509_REQ_set_version(request, 2)

        self.add(name: email, type: .email)
        self.add(name: hostName, type: .hostName)
        self.add(name: organizationalUnit, type: .organizationalUnit)
        self.add(name: organization, type: .organization)
        self.add(name: countryCode, type: .countryCode)
        self.add(name: city, type: .city)
        self.add(name: state, type: .state)

        X509_REQ_set_subject_name(request, name)

        self.setPublicKey()
    }

    deinit {
        X509_REQ_free(request)
        X509_NAME_free(name)
    }

    private func add(name: String, type: NIDType) {
        var buff = Array(name.utf8)
        X509_NAME_add_entry_by_NID(self.name, OBJ_txt2nid(type.rawValue), MBSTRING_UTF8, &buff, Int32(buff.count), 0, 0)
    }

    private func setPublicKey() {
        let certKey = EVP_PKEY_new()
        EVP_PKEY_set1_EC_KEY(certKey, key.secretKey)

        X509_REQ_set_pubkey(request, certKey)
        X509_REQ_sign(request, certKey, EVP_sha256())

        EVP_PKEY_free(certKey)
    }
}
```

**Note** This code does not contain any BIO related functions ( yet ) to write out the PEM data to a file or to a data buffer, but they are really easy to add.

**Disclaimer:** I am not a professional cryptographer nor do I know all the ins and outs of the OpenSSL API. I cannot guarantee that the code I provided is a 100% correct implementation. Always be wary of code, especially crypto code, downloaded from the web.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not a straight OpenSSL implementation, I encountered [outfoxx's Shield library](https://github.com/outfoxx/Shield) which makes it super easy to create CSRs via Swift.

Comment: Hey! I'm looking into this now but I can't find a way to create the CSR using that library, do you have an example?